# How to click the snackbar button in Espresso testing?

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-snackbar

I don't believe that this is a dupe question. I am writing a simple Espresso test and part of it involves clicking a "Ok" button in a snackbar.

```
Espresso.onView(allOf(withId(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text), withText(R.string.permission_snackbar)))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
Espresso.onView(withText("Ok")).perform(click());
```

This throws

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing
>   'single click' on view 'with text: is "Ok"'. Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the
>   target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
>   at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
>   Target view: "AppCompatButton{id=2131558552, res-name=snackbar_action,
>   visibility=VISIBLE, width=264, height=144, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=684.0,
>   y=53.0, text=Ok, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

Any ideas?

Comment: "I don't believe that this is a dupe question." Of course not, no one ever does. If you're going to explain why this is not a dupe, give *specific reasons* why *specific existing questions* did not answer your question; otherwise, don't even bring it up.

Comment: I have pretty much the same issue, how did u solve it?

Answer (score 8):

The `RuntimeException` seen here `java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints: at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.`. The issue does, in fact come from a failure of the `View` to be fully displayed.

The issue is caused by a race condition.  You are attempting to open the view, and during it's opening you are attempting to click it.  If the timing isn't right, then less than 90% of the `View` will be available for the Espresso framework to `click()`.  You may be able to resolve the issue by disabling animations, as recommended in [The Espresso Setup Instructions](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/#setup-your-test-environment)

- Navigate to you phone's `Developer Options`
- Set the following

  - Window animation scale = 0.0x
  - Transition animation scale = 0.0x
  - Animator duration scale = 0.0x

My own testing indicates that you can get away with just setting the `Transition Animation Scale` to `0.0x`.  As you can imagine, this is a perfectly consistent solution to the race condition that you're experiencing.

Answer (score 4):

It can simply be found using the id `snackbar_action`:

```
onView(allOf(withId(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action)))
    .perform(click());
```

Comment: if you take a good look at the OP, you'll see that the matcher worked.  My answer discusses the race condition causing this problem.